# Plankalkül compiler / interpreter

Tags: scientific-computing, history

I am looking for a compiler or interpreter for [Plankalkül](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plankalk%C3%BCl), the first high level (machine-independent), von Neumann - language ever invented.

It would be ideal if it could be compilable on a Linux command line, but any  solution would make me happy.

The FU-Berlin version (linked even from the Wiki page) is from 2002 and doesn't compile on current linuxes without major modifications.

Comment: Did you ever find one?

Comment: @gerrit No. Actually it was even hard for me to find a specification. I think now, the fu-berlin version could relative easily actualized, and that should be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an interpreter, but its last commit is 1 year ago:
https://github.com/peter-shoes/plankalkul

> This is an interpreter written in java for the Plankalkül language, originally created by Konrad Zuse. I found that there was only a compiler written, and it required you to use the 2D matrix originally designed by Zuse. This interpreter allows you to use the updated "Plankalkül 2000", or linearized Plankalkül, developed by Raúl Rojas, Cüneyt Göktekin, Gerald Friedland, Mike Krüger, Olaf Langmack, and Denis Kuniß.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/66173)